# Is this a bad encryption practice?

Tags: c#, security, authentication, encryption, cryptography

So I am trying to encrypt my files and authentication password.
I am currently using (A)Password Derived Byte[], (B)Clear Byte[] and a strong (C)string to encrypt it.

In my program, I hardcoded the (A)Password Derived in there. I also harcoded a (B)Encrypted version of Clear Byte[] and a (C)Encrypted version of string.

To decrypt my file/password, I must:
1. Decrypt Encrypted version of (B)Clear Byte[] using (A)Password Byte.
2. Decrypt Encrypted version of (C)String using (A)Password Byte.
3. Use the (B) Clear Byte, (C) Clear string to decrypt the file/password.

If this is not a good practice, could someone please provide me suggestions/methods I should use ?
I am developing it in c#

Comment: You would be better off actually posting the code. If it's working code you want reviewed for flaws/best practices etc then use Code Review instead of Stack Overflow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202011/encrypt-decrypt-string-in-net/10366194#10366194

Comment: I was using this example:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5719/Simple-encrypting-and-decrypting-data-in-C

Comment: Please describe in more details what are you trying to do in the application. You want to encrypt your files with password, or something else?

Comment: I want to encrypt a file that could only be opened and read by my program. I also want to have an authentication with a server, I guess i'll be going with hashing on the authentication.

Comment: If you want authentication, then GCM mode will provide it without having to do any extra work on HMACs or whatever.

Comment: If you open your executable in a text editor you will be able to see the hardcoded strings. That is not very safe.

Comment: I understand that but I'm not quite sure where else to store it.
I'll be obfuscating my code so hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with my own approach mentioned above because no one was able to post a answer I could use.

Comment: So basiclally you go with fake security? Hint: your Approach has None.

Comment: I'm using this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5719/Simple-encrypting-and-decrypting-data-in-C

is that fake security ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want something that only your program can read then you should use DPAPI. In C# This is wrapped up in the [ProtectedData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx) class.

Your code is not safe, the code could easily be reverse engineered and decrypted. Using DPAPI means that only your user can access the data you protect in your application.

You use the `protecteddata` class like this:

```
ProtectedData.Protect( data, s_aditionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser );
```

Comment: I should point out that only the _user_ can read this data, however another app using the salt could unprotect the data. But this is more secure than your original code.

Comment: I would need something universal, meaning a user can save the data, but also able to read it in another computer.